# snips-nlu not getting installed on docker

Tags: docker, rust, nlu

**Issue**:
I am installing snips in docker with step 1 given in **To Reproduce** section. I am ending with No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler' error. I am running everything on Linux based system. is there alternative way to install snips-nlu in docker?

**To Reproduce**
Created installSnips.sh (following) file for installing rust, rust setup tool

```
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install scipy
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
pip3 install setuptools-rust
source ~/.cargo/env
pip3 install snips-nlu
```

while running installSnips.sh pip3 install snip-nlu enter in following error

```
Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      /tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py:123: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
        from numpy.distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext  # noqa
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py", line 303, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py", line 295, in setup_package
          from numpy.distutils.core import setup
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 24, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 19, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 28, in <module>
          from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: requests, pyaml, packaging, scikit-learn, deprecation
  Attempting uninstall: scikit-learn
    Found existing installation: scikit-learn 1.1.2
    Uninstalling scikit-learn-1.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-1.1.2
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for scikit-learn did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
      /tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py:123: DeprecationWarning:
      
        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html
      
      
        from numpy.distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext  # noqa
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py", line 303, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-h9opcxf9/scikit-learn_fc42ebd0e5804549ad6f611dced79620/setup.py", line 295, in setup_package
          from numpy.distutils.core import setup
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 24, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 19, in <module>
          from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
        File "/home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 28, in <module>
          from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of scikit-learn
  Moving to /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikit_learn-1.1.2.dist-info/
   from /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~cikit_learn-1.1.2.dist-info
  Moving to /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikit_learn.libs/
   from /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~cikit_learn.libs
  Moving to /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/
   from /home/drjslab/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/~klearn
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> scikit-learn

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

**Environment:**

- Base OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Base Python version: 3.8
- snips-nlu version:Latest
- Docker OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker Python: 3.10.4

Answer (score 1):

It seems a recent update of `setuptools` broke `numpy.distutils` which is a dependency of `scikit-learn`.

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3505

A reported possible solution is to install `setuptools<65` with `pip install --no-use-pep517`

Comment: Yes, This solution works for me. FYI: it forces me to update "pip3 install --upgrade cython". But it works.